# Can I catch "An unhandled win32 exception" caused by an executable I'm calling from a TCL script?

Tags: exception, exec, tcl

```
catch { exec asdf.exe args }
```

The executable whose name I am passing to the exec command causes an unhandled exception.
catch { exec ...} seems to only catch non-zero return codes, not exceptions.
What's the proper way to handle this?

Note I've no access to the source code of the executable I am calling.

Comment: No, you can never catch exceptions raised in another process.

Comment: No, you cannot do that, unless you used some weird Tcl embedded in some kind of debugger.

Comment: What about catching all output in a variable, and using a regex to find a clue to your exception?

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Hans Passant and schlenk, you cannot catch an exception from an external application.

As you have already observed, `catch { cmd }` will only inspect return codes.

What you can do with `catch`, however, is capture all the output in a variable by doing:

`catch {exec asdf.exe args} err_msg`

This will set the output from the command as variable `$err_msg`.

`catch` also conveniently returns a `1` iff the command returns a non-zero code, allowing you to do the following:

```
if {[catch {exec asdf.exe args} err_msg]} {
    # inspect your output in $err_msg here;
} else {
    # successful execution aftermath here;
}
```

[NB: Incidentally, should the command return a `0`, `$err_msg` still contains the output from the command.]

Assuming your external application prints something sensible on exception, you should be able to inspect what gets printed and react accordingly.